# drive api bad request 400 when creating a form file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms

***I am trying to create a new form with drive api and I am getting bad request response, anyone knows what is missing here? I think mimeType and Title should be enough, any thoughts?***

Request

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UCYtStTpi_L_pjYdzUegofa6dVQMnEYY06Z39eZWYlMym8wnZu2j3ndsIagg
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer


{
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.form",
 "title": "fff.form"
}
```

Response

400 Bad Request

Show headers -

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```